# Externalize the sonar configuration properties to gradle.properties file in user home

Tags: gradle, sonarqube

I want to Externalize the sonar configuration properties from build.gradle file to gradle.properties file.

for example,
apply plugin: 'sonar-runner'

sonarRunner

sonarProperties

```
                property "sonar.java.coveragePlugin", "jacoco" 
                property "sonar.host.url", "http://10.42.58.229:9000/"
                property "sonar.jdbc.url", "jdbc:mysql://10.42.58.229:3306/sonar"
                property "sonar.jdbc.driverClassName", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
```

I want to pass the property values from gradle.properties file, which is present in user home.

Answer (score 8):

This is possible but the trick is that you have to use system properties (using *systemProp* prefix):

```
systemProp.sonar.host.url=http://localhost:9000
systemProp.sonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost/sonar
systemProp.sonar.jdbc.username=sonar
systemProp.sonar.jdbc.password=sonar
systemProp.sonar.login=admin
systemProp.sonar.password=admin
```

See:
https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+Gradle#AnalyzingwithSonarQubeScannerforGradle-Globalconfigurationsettings

This should work with the old 'sonar-runner' plugin but feel free to give a try to new 'org.sonarqube' plugin:
https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/org.sonarqube